# Remote desktop client MAC address

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

Is it possible to determine client mac-address in remote desktop services session? Clients connect over internet. How can I get it?  Server: Win Server 2008 R2 or 2012

Comment: It's not possible. The MAC address is replaced at every router in between the client and the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot get the MAC address of a Remote Desktop client, unless the server and the client are on the same subnet.